# How can I call non-existent functions in C++

Tags: c++, events

So, I want to know how I can call functions from header...

To explain it better, I have a header file, which is something similar to a game library.

I want to call certain functions in the Main part of the program(the dynamic one), but I want these functions not to be required.

So, if I click a hotkey combo, I'd call a function in Main part of the program called "hotkeyHit", but first I need to check if it's there. I'm implementing some kind of an "Event system".
And that's where I hit the wall...
First of all I don't know how to check if there is that function in the Main, I can't compile if there is no function called that and last of all, I can't declare the same function for second time, which leaves me with no obvious options.

So now I'd like to know how I can do that so it would work the way I want it to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a class with dummy implementations of each of your handlers. Inherit from it with concrete implementations of anything you want to handle. Pass an instance of that inherited class into the event system. When it calls the method corresponding to an event, if the concrete implementation exists it'll call it. If not, nothing will happen.

Comment: Steve, thanks I'll try to do that and will reply with additional questions if those arise.

Comment: Make sure you understand how polymoprhism works in C++ - in particular, think about references, and the `virtual` keyword

Comment: @MGlolenstine Also have a look at the [_Chain of Responsibility_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) design pattern.

Comment: @Jarod42 how would I check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after getting some help from you guys and figuring it out online, I've found a solution that works for me.

I've set it up like so:

Main code:

```
void mouseClicked();

void main(){
    setMouseClicked(mouseClicked);
}

void mouseClicked();
```

Header code:

```
void (*mc)() = NULL;
void setMouseClicked(void (*fun)(void)){
    mc = fun;
}
```

and then in the event function I do this:

```
void handleMousePress(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
    mouseButton = button;
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN){
        if(mc != NULL)
            (*mc)();
    }
}
```

I've worked on a compromise by having a declaration of the function in the main part of the code and having a setter for that function, but with that I've added an ability for renaming functions that are called when the event is triggered.

So once again, thanks for your suggestions, but at the end I've found that pointers to functions work the best.

Answer (score 0):

Some example clode below to hopefully explain my comment. In this, the methods in the `CBaseHandler` class are intentionally empty. Your Event Handler takes a reference to a `CBaseHandler` and in this example tries to handle a keypress and a mouseclick. However, the concrete implementation of the handler, `CHandler` only implements the Keypress handler (in this case just by printing a string, but you can do whatever you want)

When the Event Handler runs, only the Keypress will do anything. Presumably you'll be wanting to call that in a loop of some description in real life.

The event handler loop in your library can now take any implementation of an event handler for whatever purposes you need.

```
#include <iostream>

class CBaseHandler
{
public:
    virtual void handleKeyPress(int i)
    {
    }

    virtual void handleMouseClick(int i)
    {
    }

};

class CHandler : public  CBaseHandler
{
public:
    virtual void handleKeyPress(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived - KP" << std::endl;
    }
};

void DoHandle(CBaseHandler& handler)
{
    handler.handleKeyPress(4);
    handler.handleMouseClick(0);

}

int main() {
    CHandler myhandler;

    DoHandle(myhandler);
}
```

Comment: So I do have to call a function within a class? Is there no way to just call a normal function?

Comment: What's the problem with classes & methods? You tagged it as C++ so I assumed basic C++ functionality would be ok.

Comment: Well... there is no problem regarding classes, but I'm trying to make something that's easy to use for someone coming from Java. I was thinking more along the lines of just calling a normal function like `void keyPressed()` and that'd be it. If there is no way to get to the above, I'll use classes. thanks :D

Comment: if I have a pre-declared function in header and then I create a function with the same name in Main, I can call it without problems, so that's what I'm trying to go for.

Comment: Does the `handleKeyPress` in CHandler have to be virtual and private?

Comment: @KillzoneKid Needs to be `virtual`, probably shouldn't be `private` - I'll change that.

Comment: What I meant was, should you use override keyword instead of virtual, since it is virtual anyway?

Comment: @KillzoneKid You can do, and it's probably not a bad idea if you're using C++11 onwards. But it's not necessary to demonstrate the principle of polymorphism. In the same way as you could make some bits `inline` or `const`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function declared in header file but not defined anywhere, this will compile fine. However if you attempt to use this function anywhere in the code, the linker will complain when you try to compile it as it won't be able to find the definition. So you could simply add dummy definition which does nothing.

header.h

```
void myFunction();
```

source.cpp (1)

```
int main()
{
    myFunction(); // linker error on compile
    return 0;
}
```

source.cpp (2)

```
void myFunction() {}; // dummy definition

int main()
{
    myFunction(); // no problem
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works well, thanks, but can I put this dummy definition inside of the header? So if I don't need it in the main code, I don't have to have it?

Comment: Because of the way how header files get processed and included, you need to put definition in .cpp file

Comment: Ah... ok that's fine... Thanks for your help!